# Spark making an RDD from values of Iterable type

Tags: apache-spark

I have an RDD of (Int,Iterable[String]), How to make an RDD from iterable part?

```
scala> val salgrp=salname.groupByKey
salgrp: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Iterable[String])] = ShuffledRDD[11] at groupByKey at <console>:41
scala> salgrp.collect
18/09/04 20:51:06 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at <console>:44, took 1.723661 s
res0: Array[(Int, Iterable[String])] = Array((50000,CompactBuffer(Bhupesh, Tejas, Dinesh, Lokesh)), (10000,CompactBuffer(Sheela, Kumar, Venkat)), (45000,CompactBuf
fer(Pavan, Ratan, Amit)))
```

Comment: It is unclear if the Iterable values are single entry RDDs or should they be an RDD with just Int stripped off? I.e. are you expecting 1 RDD entry per Iterable? Or are you expecting the k to be married with the iterable v entry?

Comment: (5000,Bhupesh),(5000,tejas),(5000,Dnesh) like this,
i used this command,
val rddgrp=salgrp.flatMap{ case (k, vs) => vs.map(v => (k, v)) }

Answer (score 0):

Function "flatMap" can be used:

```
val data = List((1, List("one", "two", "three")))
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
rdd.flatMap(v => v._2).foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
```